# Yet another aspnet file path question

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm going to have a folder of word document templates for a web app. I would like to use relative paths this time. When developing, I intend to use a subfolder in App_Data, but in some real configurations it will probably point to a network share.

Before reinventing the wheel, is there any built in method in aspnet (mvc) that gives a full path from:

- A web app relative path outside the web app folder
- A relative path within app_data
- A full path

The relative (or full) path is retrieved from appSettings if it matters.

Clarification: I'm wondering if there's **a single built in method** that can handle all of theese cases as it's argument, not so much solutions for the separate cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the correct answer is "no".

Answer (score 3):

> A web app relative path outside the web app folder

You cannot have a relative path outside web app folder. Relative paths in ASP.NET are always relative to the root `~/`.

> A relative path within app_data

```
var appData = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
var fullFilePath = Path.Combine(appData, "foo.txt");
```

> A full path

you already have a full path

Comment: Does Server.MapPath(fullPathToAppData) == Server.MapPath("~/App_Data") ?

Comment: Is "~/../../MyFolder" an invalid path?

Comment: `~` represents your initial path, so, no need to go back the tree with `..\` as you already start in the beginning

Comment: @Carl R, `Server.MapPath` should be used with relative path only. `~/../../MyFolder` is outside of the web application root and so invalid relative path.

Comment: I was trying to ask if there was a built in method that could handle all of theese three paths as argument. I was probably too vague.

Comment: @balexandre, I wrote a relative path outside the application.